# Retrieving column names along with their values as an array while having the ability to change the column name. - PHP Excel

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

I have this data on my **csv file**

[image]

I was wondering if there would be any possibility to retrieve the data as an array using loop **by the use of PHP Excel's functionality**.

Like was shown below:

**Note:** I manually input the values not by retrieving the data from csv file.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Email Address] => email11@gmail.com
            [First Name] => Guy 11
            [Last Name] => Stand 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Email Address] => email12@gmail.com
            [First Name] => Guy 12
            [Last Name] => Stand 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Email Address] => email13@gmail.com
            [First Name] => Guy 13
            [Last Name] => Stand 13
        )
)
```

And by any chance if there were any functionality to change the column name, so it would be like

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Sample New Column Name Hurray] => email11@gmail.com
            [New Colum Name] => Guy 11
            [Last Name] => Stand 11
        )
```

Any help would be apprecited.

Comment: Why have you tagged this question as "PHP excel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps that you need to follow in order to solve your problem:

- Use [**`str_getcsv`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to parse csv string into array.
- Use for loop to iterate through the array that you will get from step-1.
- Within for loop, change the key to what you want. You can do this easily by making entirely new array with the keys you want.

Comment: Never thought I don't have to use like Php Excel, thanks for this!

Comment: @WesleyLachenal - If you're only working with CSV files, then you don't need PHPExcel; PHP has had built-in CSV file handling for many years